# Are there infinite sets of axioms?

Tags: logic, axioms

I'm reading Behnke's *Fundamentals of mathematics*:

> If the number of axioms is finite, we can reduce the concept of a consequence to that of a tautology.

I got curious on this: Are there infinite sets of axioms? The only thing I could think about is the possible existence of unknown axioms and perhaps some belief that this number of axioms is infinite.

Comment: Might be a useful post <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309147/system-with-infinite-number-of-axioms>

Comment: Due to the presence of axiom schemata, $ \sf ZFC $ has an infinite number of axioms. However, more can be said, namely, that it is **not finitely axiomatizable**. This means that it is impossible to replace the infinitely many axioms of $ \sf ZFC $ by a finite list.

Comment: @HaskellCurry Propositional calculus can get founded with axioms and a rule of substitution.  Even in that system though we can always get more axioms if we have countably infinite variables.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In first order Peano axioms the principal of mathematical induction is not one axiom, but a "template" called an [axiom scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema). For every possible expression (or "predicate") with a free variable, $P(n)$, we have the axiom:

$$(P(0) \land \left(\forall n: P(n)\implies P(n+1)\right))\implies \\\forall n: P(n)$$

So, if $P(x)$ is the predicate, $x\cdot 0 = 1$ then we'd have the messy axiom:

$$(0\cdot 0=1 \land \left(\forall n: n\cdot 0 =1\implies (n+1)\cdot 0=1\right))\implies \\\forall n: n\cdot 0 = 1$$

Our inclination is to think of this axiom scheme as a single axiom when preceded by "$\forall P$", but in first-order theory, there is only one "type." In first-order number theory, that type is "natural number." So there is no room in the language for the concept of $\forall P$. [In second order theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction), we can say $\forall P$.

In set theory, you have a similar rule, the ["axiom of specification"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#3._Axiom_schema_of_specification_.28also_called_the_axiom_schema_of_separation_or_of_restricted_comprehension.29) which lets you construct a set from any predicate, $P(x,y)$, with two free variables:

$$\forall S:\exists T: \forall x: (x\in T\iff (x\in S\land P(x,S)))$$

(The axiom lets you do more, but this is a simple case.)

which essentially means that there exists a set:

$$\{x\in S: P(x,S)\}$$

Again, there is no such object inside set theory as a "predicate."

For most human axiom systems, even when the axioms are infinite, we have a level of verifiability. We usually desire an ability to verify a proof using mechanistic means, and therefore, given any step in a proof, we desire the ability to verify the step in a finite amount of time.

Answer (score 18):

Many important theories, most significantly first-order Peano arithmetic, and ZFC, the most commonly used axiomatic set theory, have an infinite number of axioms. So does the theory of algebraically closed fields.

Comment: Specifically, in Peano, mathematical induction really describes and infinite set of axioms.

Comment: I remember of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/what-is-wrong-in-my-proof-that-90-95-or-is-it-correct/50512#50512) I thought that there's an axiom for every number, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think that's true, @GustavoBandeira.

Comment: Among the commonly encountered, there are also the theories of vector spaces over a given (infinite) field, of fields of characteristic zero...

Comment: More interestingly, $ \sf ZFC $ is *not* finitely axiomatizable, as first demonstrated by Richard Montague using the Reflection Principle.

Comment: @HaskellCurry $\mathsf{PA}$ is also not finitely axiomatizable, for a very similar reason.

Answer (score 11):

Are there infinite sets of axioms?  Yes!

As a trivial (and somewhat meaningless) example, consider the first-order language whose only non-logical symbols are the constant symbol $0$ and the unary function symbol $S$.  Then the following would comprise an infinite set of axioms:

- $0 \neq S(0)$;
- $S(0) \neq S(S(0))$;
- $S(S(0)) \neq S(S(S(0)))$;
  $\vdots$
- $S ( S ( S ( \cdots ( 0 ) \cdots ) ) ) \neq  S ( S ( \cdots ( 0 ) \cdots ) )$
  $\vdots$

For a more meaningful example we have, as others have pointed out, Peano Arithmetic.  More than just being an infinite list of axioms, this theory *necessarily* has an infinite set of axioms.  By a result of C. Ryll-Nardzewski, (assuming it is consistent) Peano Arithmetic is *not finitely axiomatisable*: there is no finite set of axioms (in the same language) that has the same collection of formal theorems.  (A similar result holds for ZF(C).)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps surprisingly even the classical (Łukasiewicz's) axiomatization of propositional logic has an infinite number of axioms. The axioms are all [substitution instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_instance) of

- $(p \to (q \to p))$
- $((p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r)))$
- $((\neg p \to \neg q) \to (q \to p))$

so we have an infinite number of axioms.

Usually the important thing is not if the set of axioms is finite or infinite, but if it is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidable_set). We can only verify proofs in theories with decidable sets of axioms. If a set of axioms is undecidable, we can't verify a proof, because we can't tell if a formula appearing in it is an axiom or not. (If a set of axioms is only [semi-decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set), we're able to verify correct proofs, but we're not able to refute incorrect ones.)

For example, if I construct a theory with the set of axioms given as

> $T(\pi)$ is an axiom if $\pi$ is a representation of a terminating program.

Then I can "prove" that some program $p$ is terminating in a one-line proof by simply stating $T(p)$. But of course such theory has no real use because [nobody can verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) such a proof.

Comment: Your semi-decidable set of axioms, however, proves the **same theorems** as the _decidable_ one where the axioms are those $$\underbrace{x=x\land \cdots\land x=x}_{n\text{ conjuncts}}\land T(m)$$ where $m$ is the representation of a program that terminates in $n$ steps. (Every semi-dedicable set of axioms is equivalent to a decidable one in essentially this way).

Comment: You can have a recursively enumerable axiom set - it just requires all proofs to include the amount of time before enumerating the axiom. The above is recursively enumerable, so we can prove things in it. The axiom system $S(\pi)$ meaning that $\pi$ does *not* terminate is not recursively enumerable, and therefore we can't write checkable proofs in that theory.

Comment: Lukasiewicz's axiomitization didn't actually use axiom schema.  It had 3 axioms and the rule of uniform substitution, which consists of a rule of inference.  So actually, the system you've referenced only has 3 axioms.  However, even with each axiom as finite, the possible axiomizations of classical propositional logic are infinite since (p→(q→p)) can get replaced by any theorem of the system {(p→(q→p))} under condensed detachment, and since {(p→(q→p))} under condensed detachment has an infinity of theorems.  For example, (p→(q→p)) could get replaced by (a→(b→(c→(d→(p→(q→p))))).

Answer (score 5):

An example of an infinite set of axioms used for practical use is the foundation of non-standard analysis.

Create a first-order language whose symbols include:

- Every element of $\mathbb{R}$
- Every element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$
- Every element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$
- :

Now select a set of axioms to be the set of all true statements in this language.

This language and set of axioms is enough to do lots of things; e.g. any theorem you've learned in calculus can be stated in this language and is automatically a theorem.

By general properties of first-order logic, this set of axioms is consistent and thus there exists a non-standard model! By construction, every theorem you know about 'standard' things is automatically true for non-standard things as well! In this formulation, the transfer principle from non-standard analysis -- every 'standard' object has a nonstandard analog, and every statement of 'standard' analysis is true if and only if its translation to the non-standard model is true -- becomes an utter triviality.

While one can surely attempt to select a smaller set of axioms, there is no actual reason to; for the specific application we have to apply logic in this instance, it is by far easier and more convenient to take all of them.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, first order PA has an infinite number of axioms. But it is worth stressing that this is *not* just a superficial feature of the usual mode of presenting the induction axioms via a schema or template. It is provable that there is no finitely axiomatized theory in the language of PA whose theorems coincide with those of PA.

Comment: Someone _did_ mention this in another answer. ;-)  (BTW: I just pre-ordered a coy of your _Introduction to Gödel's Theorems_ text earlier today.  Looking forward to thumbing through it!)

Comment: Ooops, sorry @ArthurFischer: very careless reading by me. Enjoy Gödel!

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the matter maybe a bit more clear giving another example:

Similar to what André Nicolas stated, $ACF_0$ (the theory of algebraically closed fields of charateristic $0$) is axiomatized by $ACF$(the theory of algebraically closed fields) + $\{\neg\phi_p$ : $p$  is  prime$\}$, where $\phi_p$ says "I have characteristic $p$." $ACF$ is already not finitely axiomatizable itself but I am sure observing that $\{\neg\phi_p$ : $p$  is  prime$\}$ is an **infinite set of axioms** is way more obvious.